# Can cucumber plugin for eclipse do the job of rubymine?

Tags: ruby, eclipse, cucumber

I am a cucumber new jack. I have heard of rubymine being very good for creating feature and step definition files. Can eclipse with cucumber plugin do the job as good? The problem is that eclipse is open source and free, rubymine is not. Open source tools are good for constant practice. Can someone please advise? Also, has anyone got a detailed documentation for cucumber plugin for eclipse? Thanks

Comment: Are you implementing any automation for your step definitions?

Comment: No, I am just looking at creating plain text file in an editor and was looking for which editor is very good for this purpose but open source

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a Jetbrains tool for writing the features, try the free version of IntelliJ IDEA. It will allow you to write scenarios with syntax highlighting.

I assume that the Ruby version of Cucumber also displays missing code snippets when you run so having another tool for writing the steps may be overkill.